# alert or console is not firing for Global Ajax Event Handlers

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying a demo for Global Ajax Event Handlers.

In my code, the `.load` method works, but I'm not getting any `alert`s or console messages for the various event stages (start/send/success/complete).

What could be the issue?

```
<body>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <input type="button" id="ajaxBtn" value="Send Ajax Request" />
</body>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ajaxBtn").click(function () {
            $(".result").load("test.html");
        });

        $(".result").ajaxStart(function () {
            alert("hello");
            console.log('ajaxStart triggered');
        });

        $(".result").ajaxSend(function () {
            console.log('ajaxSend triggered');
        });

        $(".result").ajaxError(function () {
            console.log("ajaxError triggered.");
        });

        $(".result").ajaxComplete(function () {
            console.log('ajaxComplete triggered');
        });

        $(".result").ajaxStop(function () {
            console.log('ajaxStop triggered');
        });

        $(".result").ajaxSuccess(function () {
            alert("hello");
            console.log('ajaxSuccess triggered');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/):

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method **should only** be attached to
> document.
>
> As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events,
> including those added with the .ajaxStart() method, **must** be attached to
> document.

If you are unable to interpret that I'll spell it out for you; the only correct method of reacting to the event is to do this:

```
$( document ).ajaxSend(function() {
    alert("hello");
    console.log('ajaxStart triggered');
});
```

Comment: so what will be the syntax then, please suggest!

Comment: got it...$( document ).

Comment: If it worked for you, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer

Answer (score 0):

In my case y use Jquery custom events.

for example

```
$('form').submit(
    function(){
        return $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data:data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            success: function( result ) {
                $form.trigger('submit:success');
            },
            error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                console.log( "Status: " + status );
                console.dir( xhr );
                $form.trigger('submit:error');
            },
            complete: function( xhr, status ) {
                $form.trigger('submit:complete');
                console.log( "The request is complete!" );
        }
    }
);


 $('form.SpecialForm').on('submit:success', myFunction1);

 $('form.OtherSpecialForm').on('submit:success', otherFunction);

 $('form.ThirdSpecialForm').on('submit:error', thirdFunction);

 $('form.OneMoreSpecialForm').on('submit:complete', oneMoreFunction);

 $('form.theLastSpecialForm').on('submit:complete', theLastFunction);
```